# Patch for Wildfly Modules vs. Fat EAR files

Tags: java, package, wildfly, patch

we do have a discussion here and i would like to know what is, in your opinions, the best way to solve our internal dispute. We currently have five+ Webapplicaiton (war). They are using four common jar's (DB Mapping, Common Filter, ...) as a base/backend. We do need to load several libraries (hibernate, jsf, cdi, jackson, gson,...) for our applicaitons to be fully functional. Now the question is - should we pack all needed libraries with each individual Webapplication, or should we patch our wildfly server such that the server will provide the nessessary libraries to each individual war file or something else.

An EAR for each application
EAR 1-X
- WAR
- common jar 1-4
- hibernate
- jsf
- ....

or one sinlge big EAR

EAR
- WAR 1-X
- common jar 1-4
- hibernate
- jsf
- ....

or with patch and small war files

WAR 1-X
- common jar 1-4

The commonly used jar's, are most likly dependent on external things like DB, such that they are linked together for the most parts and only very small variations will be appear during the software life cycle. All WAR files are basically using the same external lib's.

cheers

Comment: If these form a single application, then use an EAR

Comment: We are currently trying to use the multi-war method and it would fit our needs, but are there any drawbacks using this method. Because in my opinion i would rather deploy all dependencies once and use them. But deploying all the dependencies with each deployment again and again simply because they are 100% the same though out the web applications.